# Business Rule implementation

Tags: angularjs, api

I am implementing a product selector app with the following stack - Angular Front End, calls Springboot API's, data stored in Mongo

App Function:

The front end displays a bunch of questions with answer options (similar to a survey questionnaire). The user then provides answers to questions (say the answer to questions are in the form of radio button). As and When the user provides an answer by clicking the radio buttons, I have to compute a running score BASED on predefined business rules.

Score Computation:

Each response to every single question has a predefined integer value. However the score being computed is NOT a simple operation of the individual score. For example if there are 4 questions with 2 options for each question, the individual scores can be:

```
Q1 - YES = 1
Q1 - NO  = 2
Q2 - YES = 3
Q2 - NO  = 4
.
.
QN - YES = N
QN- NO  = N+1
```

SCORE COMPUTATION:

---

The logic for total score maybe (assuming the user has responded to the first 3 questions so far)
Q1 + 2*Q2 + 3*MAX(Q1,Q2) - 0.5Q4

IMPLEMENTATION of Score Computation:

---

While I can code the score computation logic in the front end, I prefer to use a microservice to do the score calculation by letting the UI pass the answers as and when they as provided.

QUESTION:

---

In the above approach, I will end up making multiple API calls every time the user clicks on the radio button as I have display the running score at the bottom after each response. While the logic in the the call very small and can run in less than 1/2 second, I want to see if I can avoid making the calls to begin with. DO NOTE that the inputs to the microservice is JUST an array of integers and DB access is needed. The service just consists of a single function that does basic math with a few IF/ELSE.
Wondering if there a way to load the microservice function onetime into "some place" and call this repeatedly with incurring the network overhead of calling the API. Any other solution that avoids Multiple API calls AND NOT storing this logic on UI is much appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason for not doing calculations at frontend? I mean do you need any data /inputs from database for calculations

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.